# Uploading file to Discord with webhook in PHP

Tags: php, curl, discord, webhooks

Here's what I have

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-user-id");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');

if (!isset(getallheaders()["X-User-ID"]) || !isset($_FILES["audio"])) {
    return;
}

$webhookurl = "discord url";
//$webhookurl = "https://8f13d44091009d558421159246966183.m.pipedream.net";

$json_data = [
    "content" => "<@".getallheaders()["X-User-ID"].">",
    "tts" => false,
    "file" => curl_file_create($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"], "audio/mpeg", "sound.mp3") // "@".realpath($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"])
];

if (isset(getallheaders()["X-User-ID"])) {
    $curl = curl_init( $webhookurl );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // 5 seconds
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // 5 seconds
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ));
    
    curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
}
```

All I get is a message with the `"content"` field (a mention in this case), no file though. Embeds work fine too.

Here's what I've found:

- From Discord docs: `file  file contents   the contents of the file being sent one of content, file, embeds` (pretty useless).
- [This guy here](https://github.com/m7rlin/DiscordWebhook/blob/master/lib/DiscordWebhook-v7.0.php) has code for uploading a file. I have copied his cURL headers, no dice.
- [This page](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/structure/file.html) says that you have to use `multipart/form-data`. The Discord docs say you only have to use it for embeds. Neither of which I found to be true. Embeds work fine with `application/json`, and I can't get a message *at all* with `multipart/form-data`.

What else I've tried:

- Swapping out `curl_file_create()` for the older `@/path/to/file` (see commented out above)
- Different `Content-Type`, like I said.
- `file_get_contents()`
- `move_uploaded_file()` instead of going directly from `$_FILES`.

Any ideas on what I'm missing? I guess my main problem is I'm not sure *what* format Discord expects...

Comment: Google-ing around, it looks like you should be using the file path instead of generating a file object with curl_file_create().  That being said... have you tried using an image file instead of the MP3?

Comment: Just now I tried using an absolute path, relative path, just the filename, and an http path, all with and without curl_create_file(). No luck...

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I shouldn't have been using `json_encode()` on the body, and I *was* supposed to use `multipart/form-data`. I also had to adjust some fields.