# PHP send attachment to discord webhook

Tags: php, curl, discord, php-7.4

I have a PHP file that I want to send with attachments (crashlogs) to a Discord channel. It works with CURL `Content-Type: application/json` and no file attachments. It just won't work with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and with attachments. I'm not super experienced with CURL and PHP, but the only post that had it solved didn't post the solution just that he figured it out. After hours of searching and nothing seems to work.

[Uploading file to Discord with webhook in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133851/uploading-file-to-discord-with-webhook-in-php)

Thanks for the help. I use `PHP 7.4` since Synology doesn't have `8.0` available in package center.

Create crash file

```
$now = new DateTime();
$CrashFilePath = __DIR__ ."/../crashlogs/".$now->getTimestamp().".txt";
$errorLogTextFile = fopen($CrashFilePath ,"wb");
fwrite($errorLogTextFile,"errormessagehere");
fclose($errorLogTextFile);

$hookObject = json_encode([
    "content" => "texthere",
    "username" => "nameofbot",
    "avatar_url" => "https://image.emojipng.com/608/12600608.jpg",
    "tts" => false,


], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

$headers = [ 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' ];
$POST = [ 'username' => 'Testing BOT', 'content' => 'Testing message'"];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "discordwebhookhere");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $hookObject);
$response   = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What happens when you execute the script? When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? What is the output of `curl_exec`? Is the text file correctly written to? The code you posted does seem to even make use of the text file?