# Sending an attachment/file via discord webhook

Tags: php, curl, discord, webhooks

I have been trying to figure out how to send an attachment in webhooks. I've been trying hours but cannot figure it out. I've been reading the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133851/uploading-file-to-discord-with-webhook-in-php) but I still haven't had much link. I've also been reading the [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files) but struggling to understand. Can anyone assist me?

```
<pre><?php 

$url = "WEBHOOK URL HERE";

$headers = [ 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8' ];
$POST = [
    // Message
    "content" => "Hello World!",
    
    // Username
    "username" => "testuser",

    // File upload
    "file" => curl_file_create("image.gif", 'image/gif', 'image')

];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POST));
$response   = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

I'm getting the error

```
"{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}"
```

Comment: Do not set the `Content-Type` header yourself, let cURL handle it. A `multipart/form-data` request needs a _boundary_ between the individual parts, and what that boundary string is, needs to be contained in the header. The one you specified yourself it missing it though, so the receiver won't know how to interpret this request.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I am a little confused by what you mean?

Comment: What part of "do not set that header" is confusing?

Comment: @CBroe even when I don't set it, it doesn;t work

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
"file" => curl_file_create("image.gif", 'image/gif', 'image.gif')
```

With

```
"file" => curl_file_create(realpath("image.gif"), 'image/gif', 'image.gif')
```

```
<pre><?php 

$url = "WEBHOOK URL HERE";

$headers = [ 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8' ];
$POST = [
    // Message
    "content" => "Hello World!",
    
    // Username
    "username" => "testuser",

    // File upload
    "file" => curl_file_create(realpath("image.gif"), 'image/gif', 'image.gif')

];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POST));
$response   = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Above code is only upload your own server file to discord.

If you want to get file from other URL and upload to Discord then you need to upload same file first on your own server as temp and then set this temp file here..

```
"file" => curl_file_create(realpath($tempfile), 'image/gif', 'image.gif')
```

after the

```
$response   = curl_exec($ch);
unlink($tempfile); //delete temp file if you want.
```